# B-52 inflight refuelling

Tags: refueling, b-52

I saw a photo of a B-52 - early model - just dropping off the inflight refueling boom, and the landing gear was extended.
Was this a common operation or something out of the ordinary - flight test, etc.?

Comment: There are a lot of videos on youtube of B-52 A-A refueling, none of them with the landing gear down. If what you saw was an early model/version....likely they were just testing.

Comment: Would this be the photo, or similar: https://3973lostoros.com/kc-97-refueling-b-52/

Comment: The early refueling airplanes were prop driven and slow, maybe they had the gear out to create some drag to keep them slow. @Whisky2, welcome to the site. Please edit and add a picture to your question.

Comment: Linking to the photo in question, or at least pointing us to where it's located would be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

It was a common practice because stall speed is slower in the landing configuration. The KC97 was at balls to the wall and the B-52 was slow as he could get. I was there.

From Wikipedia ([Boeing KC-97 Stratofreighter - Operational history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_KC-97_Stratofreighter#Operational_history)) :

> the KC-97's slow speed and low operational altitude complicated refueling operations with jet aircraft. B-52s typically lowered their flaps and rear landing gear to slow the aircraft enough to refuel from the KC-97. In addition, a typical B-52 refueling engagement profile would involve a descent that allowed the aircraft pair to maintain a higher airspeed (220–240 knots).

Unfortunately there's no source for this part of the text. If prospective doesn't mislead, the B-52 is at a quite high AOA wrt KC-97.
I am a source. I was there. It was the procedure. AFSC 43251 RECIP ENGINE MECH/Ride along as student Flight Engineer on KC97G Airplanes. 43rd AREFS DMAFB 1956-1957.

Comment: Are you suggesting the B-52's of the time we unable to apply (full) flaps without dropping the gear?

Comment: @Jpe61 no, just that dropping the flaps on its own wasn't enough to slow down quickly. Dropping the gear provides more drag, rapidly slowing the aircraft.

Comment: As I suspected the gear being selected down is not therefore about managing stall speed. The question specifically asks why the gear is down, not why landing configuration is selected as this answer notes.

Comment: ALL PROCEDURES involve managing Stall speed

Comment: The resulting drag created by lowering the landing gear necessitated increasing power settings, improving stability, without increasing airspeed. It was a tried and true event.

Comment: You should incorporate that to your answer, and pls do not shout at me about *all procedures involving managing stall speed*. They do not.

Answer (score -1):

@Whisky2 doesn’t post a picture of a Boeing [B-52](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_B-52_Stratofortress) with the gear down refueling, so it’s really speculation to what he was talking about with his question. @Jpe61 posts a photo of a B-52 being refueled by a Boeing [KC-97](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_KC-97_Stratofreighter) with wheels down, which could be the photo @Whisky2 referred to in his question.

What I do know is that the KC-97 has a cruise speed of 410 mph and a maximum speed of 444 mph. The B-52 has a cruise speed of 509 mph. I could not locate any documentation of what steps the Air Force took to safely lower the speed of the B-52 while refueling. This really limited window of speed is what lead to the development of the Boeing [KC-135](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_KC-135_Stratotanker).

Comment: Do you have *any* source for the claim that the B-52 was based-off the 367? I suspect the timeframes do not align

Comment: They don't. I'm pretty sure that's a mistype.

Comment: The drag of the landing gear did not help with flying more slowly, but helped to keep speed constant at low throttle settings.

Comment: I removed the references to the 367 being developed from B-52.

Comment: I removed my comment on that topic, but I question that the B52 needed to drop gear and flaps to fly at 410.  And that doing so would not overspeed both.  Do you have a source for that claim?

Comment: @MichaelHall You could be right. I know that the problems refueling the B-52 with the KC-97 became a big issue because of the very narrow window available between stall speed and max speed for refueling.

Comment: This answer only makes sense if we accept that the B-52 needed gear & flaps out at over 300 mph... which on its face seems extremely dubious. Maybe there is something more subtle going on here (IAS/TAS issues, or needing drag to keep the engines at an adequately high/responsive power setting - Peter's comment), but as it stands this answer needs citations in order to overcome the credibility issues raised.